# WPF 2 List Views Simple Selected Item Data Binding

Tags: c#, wpf, listview, data-binding

My main goal right now is to use this syntax which I have seen in working code previously:

```
{Binding SelectedItem, ElementName=JobTest}
```

My current understanding of this code is that `ElementName` overrides the regular Binding convention of the "parent" Data Context and tells the binding to pull from whatever source the other element is. `SelectedItem` obviously just filters the source to the selected one.

I wanted to get something very simple working and decided to use two `<ListView>` Elements:

```
<ListView Name="JobTest" ItemsSource="{Binding JobsTest}" Grid.Column="2" />
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding SelectedItem, ElementName=JobTest}" Grid.Column="3"/>
```

One with the regular Binding to an `ObservableCollection` the other just displaying the selected one from the first.

Here is the property I've set and used in the `DataContext`:

```
public ObservableCollection<JobViewModel> JobsTest { get; set; }
```

I set it here:

```
this.myContext.JobsTest = new ObservableCollection<JobViewModel>(data.JobModels.Select(jm => new JobViewModel(jm)));
```

The first List View IS populating with data, however, why is it that when I select an item from the first List View it is not displayed in the second? I'll be keeping an eye on this post and will be happy to oblige to any further code viewing requests. Thanks!

Comment: Is `JobViewModel` another list that implements `IEnumerable`? At the moment you bind selected item from one list to be displayed as source of items in another list control

Comment: No it is just a class which has properties like Name, Description, Schedule among others.

Comment: You cannot display single element in list control. You need some sort of content control which `DataContext` would be bound to selected item of the first `Listview`

Comment: Such as? I might try a Data-Grid or Data Template?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot bind single item to list of items. Since, as you mentioned, `JobViewModel`

> is just a class which has properties like Name, Description, Schedule among others

one way to do it is to use some sort of `Grid` or `StackPanel` to show fields of `SelectedItem`

```
<ListView Name="JobTest" ItemsSource="{Binding JobsTest}" Grid.Column="2" />
<StackPanel DataContext="{Binding SelectedItem, ElementName=JobTest}" Grid.Column="3">
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"/>
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Description}"/>
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Schedule}"/>
</StackPanel>
```

Comment: Thank you! So the real issue must have been that the controls I tried just didn't know how to display a `JobViewModel`. I made a stupid assumption that since my `ListView` was at least displaying the path to the file than my other control would also know how to do that. Here I'm explicitly showing it how :D

Comment: `ListView`, and every other `ItemsControl`, are meant to display list of items. `ItemsSource` is of `IEnumerable` type and it did not know show something which is not a list. If, for example `JobViewModel` would have some list as a property you can bind that to another `ItemsControl` and so on but you need some representation for single object.

Answer (score 1):

In case the list view selection mode allows multiple selection and you need to have a way to bind SelectedItems to your view model, you will find that SelectedItems is readonly and not bindable. Below is one of the workaround using System.Windows.Interactivity and Microsoft.Expression.Interactions. If you need these, it can be download from [here](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=10801)

**Additional namespace declaration in XAML**

```
xmlns:i="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Interactivity;assembly=System.Windows.Interactivity"
xmlns:ei="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactions"
```

**XAML:**

```
<ListView Name="JobTesList" ItemsSource="{Binding JobsTest}" DisplayMemberPath="Name"  Grid.Column="0">
  <i:Interaction.Triggers>
    <i:EventTrigger EventName="SelectionChanged">
      <ei:ChangePropertyAction TargetObject="{Binding Mode=OneWay}" PropertyName="SelectedItems" Value="{Binding Path=SelectedItems, ElementName=JobTesList}"/>
    </i:EventTrigger>
  </i:Interaction.Triggers>
</ListView>
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding SelectedItems}" DisplayMemberPath="Name"  Grid.Column="1"/>
```

**View Model:**

```
public class JobViewModel
{
  public ObservableCollection<JobViewModel> JobsTest { get; set; }
  public ObservableCollection<JobViewModel> SelectedJobs { get; set; }

  public JobViewModel() {
    JobsTest = new ObservableCollection<JobViewModel>();
    SelectedJobs = new ObservableCollection<JobViewModel>();

  }

  public string Name {
    get;
    set;
  }

  public System.Collections.IList SelectedItems {
    get {
      return SelectedJobs;
    }
    set {
      SelectedJobs.Clear();
      foreach (JobViewModel model in value) {
       SelectedJobs.Add(model);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

In example above, your ViewModel will pick up the selected items whenever the selection on ListView changed.

Answer (score 0):

The only way I've seen this to work is the following:

```
<ListView Name="JobTest" ItemsSource="{Binding JobsTest}" Grid.Column="2" />
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Path=DataContext.JobsTest, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Window}}}" Grid.Column="3"/>
```

Comment: But what about the `SelectedItem`? This simply gets me a copied view. I would like a control that updates every time I select an item on the left List View.